# x86-64 movl and cmpl difference

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, x86-64, stdatomic

Is `cmpl` instruction equivalent to `movl` + a compare. If so, what's the difference b/w: (1)

```
LBB1_2:    
     cmpl $0, _data_ready(%rip)
     je LBB1_2
```

and:
(2)

```
LBB1_2:
    movl    _data_ready(%rip), %eax
    testl %eax, %eax
    je LBB1_2
```

(1) is generated for `while (!data_ready);` where data_ready is `volatile int data_ready = 0x0;`

(2) is generated for `while (!data_ready.load(std::memory_order_acquire));` where data_ready is `std::atomic<int> data_ready(0x0);`

In both cases data_ready is set to 1 by another thread.
Intel guarantees `movl` to be atomic for aligned memory access and it seems like `cmpl` should be atomic too. If that's the case why is clang generating different codes? (I am sure there is valid reasons that's why I am asking)

Also, does this mean that a volatile variable is "equivalent" to an std::atomic on x86-64 platforms (which means nothing of course and is not guaranteed by the C++ standard).

The code that generates this is available [in this github repo](https://github.com/iyedb/atomics_test)

Comment: The fact that two different pieces of code generated a seemingly equivalent (but different) sequence of instructions is hardly noteworthy, as it happens all the time. You seem to be aware that `volatile` is not the same as (C++11) `atomic`, and you also seem to be able to look up Intel's x86 Programmer's Manual; so what exactly is the question?

Comment: The question is then, if the two sequences are equivalent, why the compiler authors bothered writing two different but at the end equivalent instructions for those two completely different concepts that are volatile and atomics. Why not use the same inst sequence for both. But then if the code generated for volatile and atomics is the same then the two are equivalent at the language level, at least on x86_64. For more context I am trying to wrap my head around the c++11 memory model, memory ordering and memory barriers.

Comment: According to AMD's Manual for AMD64, "**Single load or store operations (from instructions that do just a single load or store) are naturally atomic on any AMD64 processor [...]**", so that doesn't seem to imply `CMP` to be atomic. Also, the machine instructions are likely to be generated (by LLVM) way after the C++ code was parsed by clang (which is probably even unaware that the target platform is x86-64). The machine code generation module could be honouring clang's request for a "generic atomic load", and not risking merging other instructions with it.

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you. I will check what gcc generates.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` instruction does a bitwise `AND` of its instructions, and sets the flags based on the result of that `AND` (but the result of the `and` itself is discarded).

The `cmp` is similar in doing an operation only to set the flags, but it does subtraction instead of bitwise `AND`.

The operation doesn't really have much (if anything) to do with `volatile` or `atomic` though. To the extent that either of those affects code generation, the effect would be on the addressing mode used--i.e., where the first one compares an immediate value directly to a value in memory, but the second does a load, then manipulates the value in the register.

Comment: With regard to volatile and atomic, I am just saying that the compiler generates cmp for the code with the volatile var and mov + test for the atomic one and my question is why this diffrence? does mov somehow provides a stronger atomicity guarantee or something? Otherwise why not generate cmpl for both? When you say "an immediate value directly to a value in memory" what does you mean exactly? The cpu must load the value at that address first before it's compared to the direct value? Thanks.